# Talend Administration Center linking Job to project

Tags: talend

I'm trying to create Project and Task in TAC using MetaServletCaller.bat file.
I'm able to create a project using the bat file, but didn't get how to link or assign jobs to that project.

How to create project with the jobs using MetaServletCaller.bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talend MetaServletCaller [API](https://help.talend.com/reader/oYf9gKhmYrkWCiSua4qLeg/SLiAyHyDTjuznLR_F~MiQQ) doesn't provide any command for creating a job from an export file.  The only way to do this would be to do it in Talend studio, or programmatically using the commandline `importItems` command which allows you to import an exported job (while logged in to the project):

```
|  importItems source (dir|.zip)                        imports items                 |
|      -if (--item-filter) filterExpr                   item filter expression        |
|      -im (--implicit)                                 import implicit               |
|      -o (--overwrite)                                 overwrite existing items      |
|      -s (--status)                                    import the status             |
|      -sl (--statslogs)                                import stats & logs params    |
```

You can find the commandline API reference [here](https://help.talend.com/reader/UTmse7VFd_kBm7RLeMRC9A/g39yo1sCHTEOt8sUTBLz7g).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, there is no way to create job using MetaServletCaller API??

Comment: Not that I know of. You can create tasks from a pre-built job, but you can't create jobs in a project. Couldn't you use the commandline to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm planning to write an Java application, and in the background Jenkins to execute these actions. I came across "MetaServletCaller", so i thought there will be a way to create using this API.

Comment: I guess you could wrap the commandline commands (initRemote, logonProject, importItems) in a file, which you pass to commandline (run in file mode) inside a shell script, and have Jenkins execute this script. It's not more complicated than calling metaServletCaller :)